# SingleValueQuery Expression not working in pentaho report designer 8.0

Tags: ubuntu, pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I am migrating reports from PRD 6.1 to PRD 8.0,for me singlevaluequery expression is not working in PRD 8.0, is it a bug or do i have to do any extra configuration?

If anybody has faced similar problem then your comments are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
It was due to the jar file version of mysql.
Old version of mysql jdbc connector jar was not supporting advance function so i upgraded to latest version and now it is working fine.